# call to async method vs event

Tags: c#, events, async-await

I am developping a client library for a network application protocol.

Client code calls the library to init it and to connect to server. 
The client can of course send requests to the server, but the server can also send requests (Commands, called Cmd below) to the client.

The transport protocol is TCP/IP, so basically the client library connect to the server and make a call to an async method to retrieve the next request or response from the server in order to avoid I/O blocking while waiting for response/requests from the server.

That being said, I see two possible solutions  (only using C# constructs and no specific third party framework) in the library to allow the client to receive requests from the server :

Either offer an event in the library such as

```
public EventHandler<ReceivedCmdEventArgs> event ReceivedCmd;
```

that the client would subscribe to, in order to get notidied of requests incoming from the server.
Of course for this mechanism I will have to make an async loop in the client library to receive requests from the server and raise the event on Cmd reception.

Or the other solution would be to make such a method in the client library

```
public async Task<Cmd> GetNextCmdAsync()
```

that the client code would call in an async loop to receive the cmds.

Are these solutions kind of the same ? Is it better to fully use async/await constrcuts of C#5 and not rely on events anymore ? What are the differences ? Any recommendation, remark ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the event-driven approach is better in your case.

In fact, you're talking about an observable/observer pattern. *An unknown number of listeners/observers are waiting to do something if some command is received.*

Async/await pattern wouldn't work as well as event-driven approach, because it'd be something like *I expect one result* in opposite to *I'll do what you want whenever you report me that you received a command*.

Conceptually talking, I prefer the event-driven approach because it fits better with the goal of your architecture.

Async/await pattern in C# 5 isn't designed for your case, but it's for when some code executes an async task and next code lines should be executed after the task has received a result.

Comment: "block a thread because I guess I'm going to receive a command"  async/await doesn't block a thread.  Conceptually, both approaches are the same.

Comment: @OrestisP. I'm trying to remember why I wrote that. I think I said "it's like" instead of "it's".

Answer (score 4):

`Task` represents a single asynchronous action, such as receiving a single command. As such, [it is not directly suitable for streams of events](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2011/09/rx-and-async.html).

The ultimate library for streams of events is [Reactive Extensions (Rx)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx), but it unfortunately has a rather steep learning curve.

A newer option is the lesser-known [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/gg585582.aspx), which allows building up `async`-friendly dataflow meshes. In fact, I'm writing an `async`-friendly TCP/IP socket wrapper, and I'm exposing `ISourceBlock<ArraySegment<byte>>` as the reading stream. The end-user can then either receive from that block directly (`ReceiveAsync`), or they can just "link" it into a dataflow of their own (e.g., that can do message framing, parsing, and even handling).

Dataflow is slightly less efficient than Rx, but I think the lower learning curve is worth it.

I would not recommend a bare event - you either end up with a free-threaded event (think about how you would handle socket closure - could an event happen after disposal?) or the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern (which has its own similar problems syncing to the provided `SynchronizationContext`). Both Rx and Dataflow provide better solutions for synchronization and disposal/unsubscription.

Comment: But maybe he can sync raising command event to the UI or main thread.

Comment: That is the Event-based Asynchronous Pattern, and it has its own set of problems. For example, what happens if the event is queued to the UI thread while `Dispose` is called?

Comment: It's clear you need to take some details in account in order to make everything thread safe. Everything has its pros and cons. Dispose shouldn't be effectively called if there's an event like such working yet.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making a library, events seem better suited.

Events allow you to build the library without enforcing that a call back must be specified.

Consumers of your library decide what they are interested in and listen to those events.

Async tasks on the other hand are meant where you know that there will be delays ( IO, Network, etc.) Async tasks allow you to free resources while these delays take place, thus resulting in better utilization of resources.

Async tasks are not a replacement for events that you raise.